# SQL JOINs not working as expected

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have two MS ACCESS tables a and b like this

a: custId, custName
b: date, transId, custId, spend

I would like to know how each customer spent over a time period (eg Jan 2016), regardless of whether they actually made a transaction that month.  The SQL query I am using is

```
SELECT a.custId, SUM(b.spend) FROM b
LEFT JOIN a ON b.custId = a.custId
WHERE b.date >= #01/01/2016# AND b.date <= #31/12/2016#
GROUP BY a.custId
```

I was expecting to get a record set with all the customer ID's from table a with either the total spend (if they were active) or a NULL (if they were not).  But ACCESS only returns the spend for customers whose ID appears in Table b in the month of Jan and ignores the rest.  I am fairly sure I must have done something wrong with the query but don't know what is is.  All suggestions gratefully received.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you go back and check to see if the CUSTID's have any whitespace on them?  Also, you left part of the query out.  We can't see where the table names are.

Comment: Your `JOIN`s are backwards. Put table `A` in the `FROM` clause and table `B` in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Also, be sure to move all of the criteria for `B` into the `JOIN` clause and not the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hard to do in MS Access. First, note that you would seem to want the "a" table first, not second, so you keep all customers.

The `WHERE` turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. The normal solution in SQL would move the condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT a.custId, SUM(b.spend)
FROM a LEFT JOIN
     b
     ON b.custId = a.custId AND
        b.date >= #01/01/2016# AND b.date <= #31/12/2016#
GROUP BY a.custId;
```

However, I don't think this works in MS Access.  Instead, use a subquery:

```
SELECT a.custId, SUM(b.spend)
FROM a LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT *
      FROM b
      WHERE b.date >= #01/01/2016# AND b.date <= #31/12/2016#
     ) as b
     ON b.custId = a.custId
GROUP BY a.custId;
```

Comment: Your first example will work, you just need to put the ON clause within brackets:  `(b.custId = a.custId AND b.ddate >= #01/01/2016# AND b.ddate <= #31/12/2016#)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the WHERE statement is evaluated after the FROM clause, so it joins and then narrows the dates down. 
Use this instead:

```
SELECT a.custID, SUM(c.spend) FROM 
(SELECT * FROM b WHERE b.date >= #01/05/2016# AND b.date <= #30/05/2016#) as c
RIGHT JOIN a ON c.custID = a.custID
GROUP BY a.custId
```